# Markdown not rendering html elements

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, orchardcms

This is my Markdown variable

```
@{
    Layout="_Layout";
    var post =await Orchard.GetContentItemByHandleAsync($"alias:{Slug}");
    string markdown=post.Content.MarkdownBodyPart.Markdown;
    ViewData["Title"] = post;
    ViewData["Description"]=post.Content.Blogpost.Subtitle.Text;
    ViewData["Image"]=@Orchard.AssetUrl((string)post.Content.Blogpost.Image.Paths[0]);
   }
```

And this is how I used it within my page

```
@await Orchard.MarkdownToHtmlAsync(markdown)
```

But with all this in place, html elements are not rendering (i.e ,  and more)

here is the link to the page that is failing to render, https://thinkwide.tech/post/blockchain

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.Raw(await Orchard.MarkdownToHtmlAsync(markdown))`?

Comment: I have just tried that, Results still the same. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: In doc, their doing like this: `@await Orchard.MarkdownToHtmlAsync((string)Model.ContentItem.Content.MarkdownParagraph.Content.Markdown)` . Your "post."-prefix makes me a little unsure. https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/dev/docs/reference/modules/Markdown/

Comment: It actually does work, some how its failing to render only the html elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. I had to put the following code on the start up class under services.

```
services.AddOrchardCms().ConfigureServices(tenantServices =>
             tenantServices.PostConfigure<MarkdownPipelineOptions>(o =>
             {
                 o.Configure.Clear();
             }));
```

More info about markdown pipeline is found here: https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/dev/docs/reference/modules/Markdown/